# jQuery Validate Plugin submitHandler not firing

Tags: jquery, validation

Trying to compare dates in a booking form after jQuery Validation script returns successful.  Trying to use the validate submitHandler option but it's not firing, at least I'm not seeing the alert I put in there and the form submits no matter what dates are selected.

```
// Validate
if($('form').length > 0) {
    $('form').validate({
        rules:{
            formName: 'required',
            formEmail: 'required',
            formPhone: 'required',
            formStartDate: 'required',
            formEndDate: 'required',
            formParty: 'required',
            formDogs: 'required',
            formReferral: 'required'
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo( element.parent('div').next('div') );
          },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert('hi');
            var startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#formStartDate'));
            var endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', $('#formEndDate'));

            if(endDate > startDate) {
                alert('Please ensure your End Date is after your Start Date.');
                return false;
            } else {
                form.submit();
            }
        }
    });        

}
```

It's the same in Chrome 37, IE 11 and Firefox 26 on Windows 7.

The form is based on Bootstrap 3 and starts like:-

```
<form action="/booking" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

With submit button like:-

```
<button class="btn btn-form-submit left" type="submit" name="submitForm">Submit</button>
```

It's a big form.

Comment: form html shown has no ID to match selector used for validation

Comment: It's currently matching on the form tag, now edited sorry. validation.js is working just not the submitHandler section.

Comment: Submit event is firing here http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/xb1L9udy/